# using "== 0" with an "IF" statement

Tags: c

Are the two statement equivalent?

```
if (input != NULL && strcmp(input, "quit") == 0)
```

and

```
if (input != NULL && strcmp(input, "quit"))
```

Comment: No, because in the second example `strcmp(input, "quit")` is equivalent to `strcmp(input, "quit") != 0`. In C all non-0 values are considered to be true.

Comment: No, see @WeatherVane's comment. But you can use `!strcmp(input, "quit")`.

Comment: [man strcmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

Comment: That makes sense. If  INPUT is not "quit", but any other string such as "beer is good", the program needs to skip the instructions nested inside the IF curly brackets.

Answer (score 2):

No. The first one checks if the result of `strcmp` is 0.

The second checks if the result of `strcmp` is true. But true is equal to any other non-null value (thanks to UnholySheep for telling me as I forgot) and 0 is equal to NULL. So they're different.

These would be the same though:

```
if (input != NULL && strcmp(input, "quit") == 0)

if (input != NULL && !strcmp(input, "quit"))
```

As `!strcmp` checks if the value is false. False is equal to 0.

Comment: Technically any non-null value is considered to be `true`

Comment: That makes sense. If  INPUT is not "quit", but any other string such as "beer is good", the program needs to skip the instructions nested inside the IF curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write.

```
if(input != NULL && !strcmp(input, "quit"))
```

This is because strcmp is zero if they are equal which means it returns "false" when they are the same.  That is why you need the logical not.

Also just for your information NULL is really just a constant zero so you could also write.

```
if(input && !strcmp(input, "quit")
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, `if` statements only check if the value is `zero or non-zero`. for example `if(3)` or `if(-1)` is always works but `if(0)` won't work.

Also `strcmp()` function returns the difference between two strings, the result may be 1, 35, -27... according to your inputs. `strcmp()` results 0 if only the strings are equal.

So `if(input && !strcmp(input, "quit"))` is not `if(input && !strcmp(input, "quit") == 0)`

Comment: That makes sense. If  INPUT is not "quit", but any other string such as "beer is good", the program needs to skip the instructions nested inside the IF curly brackets.

Comment: If input is quit then strcmp(input, "quit") is 0. if(0) means don't execute if scope.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the following values:

- if Return value < 0 then it indicates str1 is less than str2.
- if Return value > 0 then it indicates str2 is less than str1.
- if Return value = 0 then it indicates str1 is equal to str2.

For your case,  strcmp(input, "quit") is not equal to 0. So the first statement will be false while the second is true.

For more, check this out: [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm)